# Tic Tac Toe 2D Char Array not updating in row=0, col=0--C

Tags: c

Apologies if this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to find the error here. I'm making a tic-tac-toe game in C. Everything in my program seems to work perfectly, except for the top left position in the array ([0][0] or 1,1 where row-1 and col-1). The human player and the computer player can both input their tokens in that spot, but it removes the token the next time a player gives a move. My code is below:

The issue I'm having looks like this:

```
The current state of the game is:
_ _ _ 
_ _ _ 
_ _ _ 
Player 1 enter your selection [row, col]: 2,1
The current state of the game is:
_ _ _ 
O _ _ 
_ _ _ 
Player 2 has entered [row, col]: 3,1
The current state of the game is:
_ _ _ 
O _ _ 
X _ _ 
Player 1 enter your selection [row, col]: 1,1
The current state of the game is:
O _ _ 
O _ _ 
X _ _ 
Player 2 has entered [row, col]: 3,3
The current state of the game is:
_ _ _ 
O _ _ 
X _ X
```

What exactly is the problem here? I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What compiler are you using for this?  It should be throwing warnings for this code.  When I tested it out, I got reports that `check_table_full`, `check_end_of_game`, and `check_three_in_a_row` can all end without properly returning a value.  My quick debugging shows that `check_three_in_a_row` will certainly run through the invalid code path as well. That alone could be causing this issue.

Comment: I am using gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the following function.  Your if statement only has a single `=` sign.  This is causing the position `0, 0` to be set to `'_'` and return false.

```
_Bool check_table_full(char board[SIZE][SIZE])
{
int a, b;
for (a=0; a<SIZE; a++) {
    for (b=0; b<SIZE; b++) {
        if (board[a][b]=='_') {  // <==== Fixed the double equal sign
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I would certainly recommend you clean up formatting as you go.  Also, you mentioned above that you were using GCC.  For a simple learning program such as this one, you should probably be compiling with `-Wall` as an option to show all warnings.  That will flag a few other issues with this code as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fix and thank you for the tips!